# Python: How can I see if a given month and day have already passed this year?

Tags: python, date

Today it's `16 Feb`. I have a string `23 Mar`. How can I check if my string is before or after the current day?

I have a list of files with the last modified date attached. They only have a day and month, no year. If the date has already passed this year (e.g. 16/01), the year should be 2014, if not (e.g. 30/12), the year should be 2013.

Comment: You should convert them to Date object first.

Comment: @杨扬-momo so nice to see Chinese characters ;P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse out the string into a `datetime` object using [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), but since your date string has no year attached to it, do attach the current year to it:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
yourdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(inputstring, '%d %b')
yourdate = yourdate.date().replace(year=today.year)

if yourdate >= today:
    # date not before today, attach *last* year
    yourdate = yourdate.replace(year=today.year - 1)
```

I converted the `datetime` object to a `date` object here too since we only need to talk about dates.

This does assume your date strings always are of the form *day-of-the-month month-abbreviated* in English.

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> inputstring = '23 Mar'
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> yourdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(inputstring, '%d %b')
>>> yourdate = yourdate.date().replace(year=today.year)
>>> yourdate
datetime.date(2014, 3, 23)
>>> yourdate >= today
True
```